# all the apples vs all apples

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

> Who ate all apples?

vs

> Who ate all the apples?

Is first question wrong?

Why after "all" is necessary to add "the"? Without "the" are they all apples in the world?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

> All the members of our family are doctors.

Is it the same logic?

Or I can say: All members of our family are doctors.

Answer (score 2):

When we use definite article **the** it specifies a particular object or objects.
 When you ask **Who ate all the apples** You are talking about those particular apples(apples that you saw, or bought).
 When you ask **Who ate all  apples?** you are talking about apples in general, therefore it seems a bit awkward.

Comment: All the members of our family are doctors.

Is it the same logic?

Or I can say: All members of our family are doctors.